# popToRoot UINavigationController when switch tab in UITabbarController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITabbarController with 2 tab bar items. Each tab bar item contains several UIViewControllers linked with a UINavigationController. I want that each time I switch tab item, the view displayed is the root. How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `UITabBarControllerDelegate`'s method `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` to track user changing tabs, and perform `popToRootViewController:` on your navigation controller being selected there.

Another rather quirky solution may involve subclassing `UINavigationController` and doing the same thing in `viewWillAppear:`.

Comment: Here's the structure : 
tabbaritem1 ->viewcontroller1
tabbaritem2 ->viewcontroller2 ->viewcontroller3
where should I use the UITabBarControllerDelegate's method ?

Comment: You should set `UITabBarController`'s delegate in the place where you create it, I guess it's your `AppDelegate`. `AppDelegate` itself may play the role of `UITabBarControllerDelegate` and implement the method. (Although this is not the cleanest practice, but it's okay for a smaller projects.)

Comment: What's the best practice?

Comment: The point here is that eventually `AppDelegate` ends up serving as a delegate for countless things and becomes littered. I'd probably have a separate object managing UI navigation, but that's about it.